# Reason for order of multiplication of ordinals

Tags: soft-question, notation, set-theory, ordinals

I understand that addition and multiplication on ordinal numbers cannot be commutative and I know why $1+\omega$ and $2\times\omega$ must be different from $\omega+1$ and $\omega\times2$, respectively. For addition, I see why $1+\omega$ is just $\omega$, because it represents a position after $1$ and then $\aleph_0$ elements, and I can include the first element into the rest and the position wouldn't change.

What I am intrigued about is why $\omega+\omega$ is equal to $\omega\times2$ and not $2\times\omega$, as I would think.

How I interpret an expression like $5×2$ is "five-times two", like two seen five-times, as in $2+2+2+2+2$. In the context of ordinals, I would also imagine the expression $\omega+\omega$ (as I see omega two-times) to be $2\times\omega$. In contrast, I would interpret an expression like $\omega\times2$ to be $\underbrace{2+2+2+...}_\omega$, which also corresponds to a set of $\aleph_0$ elements and thus be equal to $\omega$. However, the usual definition is the exact opposite.

I understand that notation is not the underlying mathematics and one may freely redefine the operator in terms of changing the order of operands, but this definition seems to me arbitrary and inconsistent. Is there any particular reason why it was defined so?

Comment: Why do you think "five times two" should be $2+2+2+2+2$ instead of $5+5$?  I don't think it is obvious.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, trying to illustrate the point in English was a bit harder. You usually think of "times" as a commutative operator in mathematics, but when you order beer five times, you get five pieces of beer before you. I intuitively interpret "five times" as a numerative unit, distinct from the nominative "two". Of course, in mathematics, it can be defined both ways equally. In other languages, it may be more apparent (or the complete opposite, as a matter of fact).

Comment: Personally, I (and most of the logicians I know, it seems) are with you: I read "$a\cdot b$" as "$a$-many $b$s" (under which interpretation $2\cdot\omega=\omega+\omega$), not "$a$ taken $b$-many times" (under which interpretation $2\cdot \omega=\omega$). Meanwhile, as Stefan observes, there are notational arguments going both ways.

Comment: This definition is due to Cantor, and he spoke German, not English.  I don't know if the connotations of multiplication are different in German (or if they were different in the German of the late 19th century).

Comment: @EricWofsey I think in German it's "fünf mal zwei", literally "five times two", and fünfmal (a single word) can also be used as a unit meaning "five times". It seems similar to my intuitions.

Comment: De gustibus non et disputandum. One cannot dispute matters of taste.  Cantor preferred it that way, and others followed it...... I would sometimes like to write a function as $(x)f$ rather than $f(x),$ as an expression like $f(g(h(x)))$ has to be read from right to left to be understood, which is fine in Hebrew, but inconvenient for me in English .

Comment: @EricWofsey: I read somewhere (can't find it now, unfortunately) that Cantor's original definition was in the opposite order compared to today's standard.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/repeated-addition-standard-notation/

Comment: @EricWofsey: I searched a little more, and now found this: [Bertrand Russell says](https://books.google.com/books?id=kXKLAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT491&dq=cantor+multiplicand) “Cantor has changed his notation in regards to multiplication: formerly [...], now [...]”. So it seems that it is indeed Cantor's fault, after all. :-)

Comment: @HansLundmark: I don't know about Cantor's earliest definition, but by 1895 at least he was using the modern definition, in his paper "Beiträge zur Begründung der transfiniten Mengenlehre" (available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140423224341/http://gdz-lucene.tc.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gcs/gcs?&&action=pdf&metsFile=PPN235181684_0046&divID=LOG_0044&pagesize=original&pdfTitlePage=http%3A%2F%2Fgdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de%2Fdms%2Fload%2Fpdftitle%2F%3FmetsFile%3DPPN235181684_0046%7C&targetFileName=PPN235181684_0046_LOG_0044.pdf&); see p. 502-503).

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is quite arbitrary. But one soft reason to define it this way is that it makes ordinal arithmetic left distributive, i.e. for all ordinals $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$

$$\alpha \cdot (\beta + \gamma) = \alpha \cdot \beta + \alpha \cdot \gamma$$

and allows for left cancellation
$$
\alpha > 0 \wedge \alpha \cdot \beta = \alpha \cdot \gamma \implies \beta = \gamma.
$$

Now, since historically these (and similar) laws have been stated predominantly for 'left variants' rather than their 'right' counterparts, it feels natural to me to define ordinal arithmetic the way it is.

---

edit: I actually also see an argument for the other position. If we consider $\alpha \cdot \beta$ it's $\beta$ that behaves more like a scalar in that, for every $\alpha > 0$ 
$$\beta \mapsto \alpha \cdot \beta$$
 is strictly increasing and, as above, $\alpha \cdot (\beta + \gamma) = \alpha \cdot \beta + \alpha \cdot \gamma$. Since modules usually have their scalars to the left (and I consider your 'beer example' to be a natural module), this might serve as an argument to define at least ordinal multiplication the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I accepted this order of multiplications by noting that $\omega^{(\omega + 1)} = \omega^\omega \cdot \omega.$

More generally, $\alpha^{(\beta + \gamma)} = \alpha^\beta \cdot \alpha^\gamma$.